# Material UI transition out and in on single button click

Tags: javascript, material-ui, transition

In the Material UI [Transitions doc](https://material-ui.com/utils/transitions/), there are examples where a button triggers a transition. I have a case where a button triggers a state change and I want the former data to transition out and then the new data to transition in. The only way I have found to do this is with `setTimeout`. Is there a better way?

[In CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/op4x52yvz)

```
import React from "react";
import Slide from "@material-ui/core/Slide";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";

const words = ["one", "two", "three"];
const transitionDuration = 500;

class TransitionCycle extends React.Component {
  state = {
    activeIndex: 0,
    elementIn: true
  };

  onClick = () => {
    this.setState({
      elementIn: false
    });
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({
        elementIn: true,
        activeIndex: (this.state.activeIndex + 1) % words.length
      });
    }, transitionDuration);
  };

  render() {
    const { activeIndex, elementIn } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <Button onClick={this.onClick}>Cycle</Button>
        <Slide
          in={this.state.elementIn}
          timeout={transitionDuration}
          direction="right"
        >
          <Typography variant="h1">{words[this.state.activeIndex]}</Typography>
        </Slide>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TransitionCycle;
```

Is this the best way to do back to back transitions in Material UI? It feels odd to use `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use CSS transitions directly and to use an event listener instead of setTimeout to detect when the transition has happened, Mozilla provides documentation on that here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions#Detecting_the_start_and_completion_of_a_transition

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  updateTransition = () => {
    this.setState({
      elementIn: true,
      activeIndex: (this.state.activeIndex + 1) % words.length
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    elementRef.addEventListener("transitionend", updateTransition, true);
  }
}
```

Don't forget to add the event listener on mounting and remove it on unmounting the component.

Answer (score 0):

I think conditionally render all 3 `Slides` could solve your problem, [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vqp2zl6o9y).

I also checked the [source codes](https://github.com/reactjs/react-transition-group/blob/master/src/Transition.js) of `Transition` and it also uses `setTimeout` in the end, so I think it's not that "weird" to use it, but if the component already wraps the low-level api (I mean setTimeout) for us then we surely don't want to use it.

---

Edit:

As OP's comment, I found that I misread his example and didn't notice the out transition, so I [modified my codes](https://codesandbox.io/s/vqp2zl6o9y) to meet the requirement. Now the previous `Slide` exits completely, then the next one enters. Everything is done by the component's designed props. (Still, the underlying `Transition` source codes are just wrapping the Rudolf Olah's method, but I just try to use only the designed props)

However, by only using `Transition`'s props, I think it's impossible to achieve the "delay" entering what OP did using `setTimeout`, so if OP still wants to have that small delay before "Two" enters, you might still have to use `setTimeout`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to maintain the out transition.

Comment: @ScottH You're right, my bad, I modified the codes, please check if it's what you need.